# paramiko proxycommand with existing tunnel

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, paramiko, tunnel

I'm using a setup where I need to ssh to a server from a client where ssh to the server is restricted to a specific bastion host. I have an existing ssh tunnel set up between the bastion host and the server (using autossh), and I would like to be able to use this in my python library. I'm trying to use ProxyCommand to do this, but I can't get my head around how. This is what I tried:

```
cmd="/usr/bin/ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=/usr/bin/nc -x <bastion-host>:<ssh-tunnel-port> %h %p' -i <identity-file> <user>@<target-host>"
sock=paramiko.ProxyCommand(cmd)
t=paramiko.Transport(sock)
t.connect()`
```

The ssh call above works when I run it as such - I am able to ssh into the target host, but not when used as the ProxyCommand - the `connect()` call just hangs.

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong w.r.t ProxyCommand? Is there something I need to change in the ssh command, or use the ProxyCommand object differently?
2. Is there some other way to achieve what I need using paramiko (without using the ProxyCommand itself)?